# Arduino: casting char to integer

Tags: casting, char, arduino, int

im getting strange issues, when casting char to int in Arduino IDE. The method should check an array of char for "IP". If there is one number ore more numbers after the chars, they should be converted to int.

```
 int getPin(char dataFromAndroid[ ]){
     for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     if(dataFromAndroid[i] == 'I') {

       if(dataFromAndroid[i + 1] == 'P') { // Digitaler Pin

        char c1 = dataFromAndroid[i + 2];
        char c2 = dataFromAndroid[i + 3];
        int digPinNr;
        char str;
        str+=c1;

        if(c2 != '0') {
          str+=c2;
        }

        digPinNr = str -'0';
        Serial.print("c1:");
        Serial.print(c1);
        Serial.print("c2:");
        Serial.print(c2);
        Serial.print("str");
        Serial.print(str);
        Serial.print("Pin:");
        Serial.println(digPinNr);
        return digPinNr;
       }
     }
   }
```

}
Sometimes the program gets 5 instead of 7 (see the outup). Can some help me please ?!

```
Empfangen:W204IP5 c1:5c2: str5Pin:5
Empfangen:W106IP5 c1:5c2: str7Pin:7
```

Comment: Is there any possibility that the char[] is being overwritten by new data between printing the whole string and the printouts in getPin? For example, does an interrupt handler change it?

Comment: Does the problem usually happen on the last line? I could see how at the end of the stream, that C2 may be pointing to invalid data (for instance, a carrige return instead of a space). In fact, when C2 is a space, you are still adfing it to your str value. You're only excluding the zero char.

Comment: You can also look into using [isdigit](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__ctype.html#ga49b21b266576c2490dab1e8f897c801a) to test if the char is numeric.

Comment: no, the array isnt overwritten, another method uses the same ressource (for example W204IP5), and should get the numbers after the 'W'. It uses basically the same code and works without problems.Im gonna try it with isdigit, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution now for the problem. I have just changed the char array to a string, and the converting is done like : `digPinNr = str.toInt();`
Here's the full solution:

```
int getPin(char dataFromAndroid[ ]){

     for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     if(dataFromAndroid[i] == 'I') {

       if(dataFromAndroid[i + 1] == 'P') { // Digitaler Pin

        char c1 = dataFromAndroid[i + 2];
        char c2 = dataFromAndroid[i + 3];
        int digPinNr;
        String str="";
        str+=c1;

        if(c2 != '0') {
          str+=c2;
        }

        digPinNr = str.toInt();
        Serial.print("c1:");
        Serial.print(c1);
        Serial.print("c2:");
        Serial.print(c2);
        Serial.print("str");
        Serial.print(str);
        Serial.print("Pin:");
        Serial.println(digPinNr);
        return digPinNr;
       }
     }
   }
```

}